# WinDbg pattern search not returning expected result

Tags: memory, windbg

I'm searching for a string, say the old "This program cannot run".

Switching context to e.g. notepad, non invasive, with page translation

```
1: kd> !process 0 0 notepad.exe
PROCESS ffff9d05d0005080
    SessionId: 2  Cid: 0368    Peb: 5c8ae78000  ParentCid: 0890
    DirBase: 30305002  ObjectTable: ffffb48e166c1440  HandleCount: 232.
    Image: notepad.exe

1: kd> .process /r /p ffff9d05d0005080
```

And sweeping for strings returns the expected result

```
1: kd> s -[l16]sa 7ff6e1760000 L100
00007ff6`e176004e  "This program cannot be run in DO"
00007ff6`e176006e  "S mode.
```

However pattern search returns with nothing

```
1: kd> s -a 7ff6e176004e L100 "This program"
```

Sanity:

```
00007ff6`e176004e  54 68 69 73 20 70 72 6f-67 72 61 6d 20 63 61 6e  This program can
00007ff6`e176005e  6e 6f 74 20 62 65 20 72-75 6e 20 69 6e 20 44 4f  not be run in DO
00007ff6`e176006e  53 20 6d 6f 64 65 2e 0d-0d 0a 24 00 00 00 00 00  S mode....$.....
```

Now if I switch context, but this time with the invasive flag

```
1: kd> .process /i /r /p ffff9d05d0005080
1: kd> g
```

And voila

```
1: kd> s -a 7ff6e176004e L100 "This program"
00007ff6`e176004e  54 68 69 73 20 70 72 6f-67 72 61 6d 20 63 61 6e  This program can
```

Since clearly WinDbg can search & find the string on it's own, why is invasive needed for it to crop up during pattern search?

Thanks

Comment: paged out headers probably  try this  or try -d 74 ,...